# Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range: requested index 6 is out of 0 to 5 in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, flatlist

Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range:
requested index 6 is out of 0 to 5

Why This Error is coming. I dont have any "scrollToIndex" in my code. But I have some flatLists.

Is it Very Big Issue. Or what . How can I fix it

Error Coming Like This

Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range:
requested index 90 is out of 0 to 89
ERROR  Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range:
requested index 90 is out of 0 to 89
ERROR  Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range:
requested index 264 is out of 0 to 263
LOG  VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 2465.90478515625, "dt": 275503, "prevDt": 2314}
LOG  VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 2465.90478515625, "dt": 275466, "prevDt": 2357}

and its keep coming after calling API and after few seconds its closing

Comment: Can you provide the error log or a screenshot of it?

Comment: Also, please post your code where you get the error. It can also be caused by a third-party library you're using. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have updated Please check

Comment: Please , can  you reproduce your issue in sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-q4qymyp2l6?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js , it will be much easier to me help you with all code